# having defficulties to load values of an arraylist into a Jcombobox in GUI design

Tags: java

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFlU0.png)

[Here, I am using the data from the SQL database and store the values into an ArrayList.Right now, I just want to load the ArrayList into my combo box which is "FacultyComboBox". However, once I write FacultyComboBox in main, it keeps saying that"non-static variable cannot be referenced from the static variable. Can someone help me with it? (loading the values in the Arraylist to FacultyComboBox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aybft.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2654F.png)

Comment: Code, not pictures of code please

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)